# Send a user message to a user via Power Automate in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

Is there a possibility to send a user message to specified user(s) in MS Teams?

**Elaboration:**
My current flow triggers a message to a user, but it is always sent via FlowBot and appears in the Power Automate chat of MS Teams. 
**Flow:** 
(Outlook; Trigger) "When a new email arrives (V3)" 
→ (MS Teams) "Post message in chat or channel" 
→ (Outlook) "Mark as read or unread" (v3)
Can individual users be set as recipients of direct messages with the message sent in the already existing chat with the user?
If yes, is it possible without a value chain?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try these Power Automate steps to create the 1:1 chat between you and the user, then send a message to it.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work for already existing (group) chats. At least not nested in an "apply to each"

Comment: How would you know what the conversationID is?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, there are kind of a few different questions in your post, so I'll try deal with each of them:

1. In order to send a message directly to a user, the user has to come "from" someone/something, and in Teams that basically means a Bot. The easiest way, therefore, to do this is to use the out-of-box FlowBot. If that's fine for you, you're good to go. If you want it to come from another Bot (i.e. one you own) then you need to create a Bot somehow. Two main options are:

- Code it from scratch using [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/) - code in a regular language (C#, Python, etc.) or using Bot Framework Composer
- Use Power Virtual Agents - ala "Power" family, it's kind of a "Drag and Drop" bot capability. You don't need to actually have the bot DO anything though, if you don't want it to handle user responses (you can do most of that visually in your Power Automate flow. For this option, you'll be able to select the bot from within Power Automate designer as the "send from" bot

2. You can choose to have the bot send a message directly to the user (i.e. in a 1-1 chat, like what you're seeing with FlowBot) or you can choose to have it send to a particular Channel inside Teams - either is fine. Be aware that Channels have threaded conversations, if you want to use them, but 1-1 chats do not.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. My question is about the second part:
Can a flow send a message from "my" 1-1 user chat to another user?

Comment: ohh, I see now what you mean. I -think- that's possible but haven't tested it - basically you can write the flow to accept the message and then send it's body to the other user.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: No, you'd have to check in Power Automate the options for getting a message from a user